# How to add non-repeating elements in value of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to put every five members of my list in a list as the value of my dictionary but the duplicate numbers should not be added in the individual values and I need to implement this program in Python in the shortest possible order.

For example if the list is `lst = [9, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]`, the result dictionary should be `d = {1: [9, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]}`.

Another example is `lst = [8, 6, 1, 9, 1, 0, 2, 8]` and the result dictionary is `{1: [8, 6, 1, 9], 2: [0, 2, 8]}`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: You second example that you added later is not consistent with your descriptions and made our answers wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```py
def fn(lst, n):
    return {
        idx: list(dict.fromkeys(lst[i : i + n]))
        for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, len(lst), n), start=1)
    }


print(fn([9, 9, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6], 5))
print(fn([8, 6, 1, 9, 1, 0, 2, 8], 5))
```

output:

```
{1: [9, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]}
{1: [8, 6, 1, 9], 2: [0, 2, 8]}
```

**Explanation**:
You need to iterate through your list with the step of `n`. Then create your slice which contains `n` items. To remove duplicates I used `dict.fromkeys()` which preserves the insertion order. Also the keys are coming from `enumerate(..., start=1)`

Answer (score 1):

An approach chunking the original array and applying a `dict.fromkeys` in each chunk and converting to dict

```py
a = [9,9,9,2,3,4,5,5,6,6]

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

l = [list(dict.fromkeys(chunk)) for chunk in chunks(a,5)]

d = {k+1:v for k,v in enumerate(l)}

print(d)
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this code :)

Comment: This works for the sample data shown in the question but is not a generic solution as it does not preserve order. For example, try *a = [9,9,1,9,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,1,1,1,1]*

Comment: Yes. This answer was right before OP added the second example

Comment: @jvx8ss It was never right. You can't use sets in this way if preservation of order is important